# Unable to run MS Access macros using Python and pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to run a msaccess macro in python and having trouble with running the query. I am using pyodbc to connect to the mdb.

```
conn_str = (
   r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
   fr'DBQ={mdb_path};'
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

The above code connects to the .mdb and appears to be successful in connecting, but I am unsure of how to run the macro now.

```
cursor.execute(f'exec {macro}')
```

I've tried the above and get the error -
('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'macro_run_vb'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly. (-1305) (SQLExecDirectW)")

macro_run_vb is the name of the macro so I know that its not a problem of it not finding the macro. Has anyone had a similar issue with running macros in python?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to run an Access macro using an ODBC connection. To do that you would need to use COM Automation. For example, to run the Macro named DropOrmTables …

[image]

you would do something like this:

```py
import win32com.client  # needs `pip install pywin32`

db_path = r"C:\Users\Public\test\gord_test.accdb"

obj_access = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Access.Application")
obj_access.OpenCurrentDatabase(db_path)
obj_access.DoCmd.RunMacro("DropOrmTables")
obj_access.Quit()
```

Comment: I'm trying to this out but im geting this error: 

`(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'You canceled the previous operation.', 'vbaac10.chm', 5738, -2146826287), None)`

Do you know what would caues this

Comment: Does the macro call StopAllMacros or try to shut down Access when it finishes?